# What happen, when epoll file descriptor is closed?

Tags: epoll

Suppose I create epoll file descriptor (epfd) by call

```
epfd = epoll_create( 10 );
```

Next I adding some count of file descriptors into this set by calling epoll_ctl(epfd,EPOLL_CTL_ADD,...) and wait for events in event loop by calling epoll_wait in separate thread.

What happened if I close epfd (by call close(epfd) in thread, other then epoll_wait thread) when epoll set is not empty and epoll_wait(epfd,...) in progress? Is epoll_wait terminated? With which results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Predictably, Linux does the same thing as it does for `select(2)`. From the manual page:

> For a discussion of what may happen if a file descriptor in an epoll
>   instance being monitored by `epoll_wait()` is closed in another thread,
>   see `select(2)`.

And from the `select(2)` page:

> If  a file descriptor being monitored by `select()` is closed in another
>   thread, the result is unspecified. [...] On Linux (and some other
>   systems), closing the file descriptor in another thread has no effect
>   on `select()`

The tl;dr; is "don't do it":

> In summary, **any application that relies on a particular behavior in
>   this scenario must be considered buggy**.

Comment: Is this still the case? The paragraph pointing to `select()`'s manual page seems to no longer be part of `epoll_wait()`'s page (while it is still present in `poll()`'s, for example).

Comment: (The documentation was changed here: https://github.com/mkerrisk/man-pages/commit/e3a60d1ce22634ab640d0efc1a8f64e3f376bccb.)